# Service Broker External Activator response take long

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, service-broker

I have two databases on SQL Server 2014, `SourceDB` and `LogDB`. On SourceDB, `Service Broker`; and on server, `Service Broker External Activator` service are activated.

On SourceDB I have TargetQueue of which a table's (Product) insert trigger sends changes on TargetQueue and TargetQueue has Event notification which nudges my external exe client. Inside exe client I finally dequeue data via `WAITFOR(RECEIVE TOP (1))..` and log them directly to LogDB.

So, when I start the SBEA service and on very first insertion into table a/a few record (after delete all records), TargetQueue immediately filled but the interval from time of insertion to SourceDB till insertion to LogDB is approx *3-6 seconds*, event notification based time consumption here I guess, not sure. For further insertions after this, the interval becomes *100ms* as seen below.

**First**

[image: First]

**Further**

[image: Further]

1. Why is the first insertion take too long, why after delete all records of table, it becomes to take long again? Why, further ones take shorter than the first?
2. Can I decrese the interval under 10ms as I can achieve the almost same structure with SQLCLR under 10ms and the fastest response is crucial for my application as well? (Both structures are on same SQL Server Instance works locally)

Comment: Service Broker is inherently asynchronous. If you want to use it as a technology, you should be designing your application with that in mind. That is, any message produced will be consumed by your process eventually. But what you're describing sounds an awful lot like you're expecting near synchronous behavior from a queue. You'll be disappointed eventually.

Comment: @BenThul I am using Service Broker beacuse it is asynchronous, as my server will be encountering high frequency of requests. In order to not to interrupt processing of these requests or stuck within one of them, I have used Service Broker instead of any synchronous structure (as I've recently given good advices here). But I am really dissapointed with this performance if it really is, so this is what I am asking indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can streamline the process by ditching the External Activator and the Event Notification.  Instead have your program continuously running WAITFOR (RECEIVE directly on the target queue in a loop.

Here's a sample to get you started: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Service-Broker-Message-e81c4316

Comment: Does it mean I should not rely on event based structure for quick response? And, polling that `Waitfor(..` statement costly for sql server?

Comment: The event notification, the external activator itself, and the fact it has to launch your external process all add time. And polling with WAITFOR (RECEIVE is not costly, so long as you use a reasonable timeout (a few seconds at least).

Comment: Thank you David, I will give a try this and get back for results.

Comment: David, could you please check Q/A of the repository you provided

Comment: I replied in the Q/A.

Comment: I have begun to form my structure by using your advice here, as long as I deep dive, I've optimized the code with a better approach, so finally I conclude my structure with [produce-consumer queue model using with Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern) Although the OP was about a performance issue on **External Activator**, however, I basically seek a better performance and this answer helped me to find my direction in right way.